# Boot Loop On Reboot After Successful Root (With KingoRoot & KingRoot)

Tags: root-access, samsung, recovery-mode, boot-loop

I first tried to root my Samsung Grand Prime (SM-G530W) a while back using KingRoot and it succeeded, but after restarted my device it got stuck in a boot loop and eventually showed the "Custom binary blocked by FRP lock" error, but after factory resetting it everything was fine again. Now, I tried to root my phone again using KingoRoot this time, once again it was successful, but now it's stuck in another boot loop and there is no error message. I tried booting into recovery mode and factory resetting, but the problem still occurs. What can I do???

Also, I only have today and tomorrow to figure this out, so I posted this EVERYWHERE.
Here's the thread on other websites, see if you can find any useful info:

- http://forums.androidcentral.com/general-help-how/717089-boot-loop-reboot-after-successful-root-kingoroot-kingroot.html?mn_qa=1#post5369840
- http://www.androidauthority.com/community/threads/boot-loop-on-reboot-after-successful-root-with-kingoroot-kingroot.30729/

There's also 3 more, I'll link them if I get at least 10 rep (it's required).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by following this YouTube video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lWuH7Km6GSQ